# compare 2 txt file and print matches line

Tags: perl

i have list1.txt contine 100 names
i want to get the emails of them from the list2.txt that contain 1000 names with emails like that (name : email) 
its very tired to search for names one by one 
so i want to get the lines that continue the names and email of my 100 names that i serch for in one click
simple

list1.txt (names) the list of my 100

```
name1
name2
name3
etc
```

list2.txt  (name : email)  the big list that i want to extract the mails of my list name

```
name2:whatever@gmail.com
name1:whatever@gmail.com
name3:whatever@gmail.com
name4:whatever@gmail.com
name5:whatever@gmail.com
```

so i want to print the lines that contain the names  (name1 and name2 and name 3.etc)

```
name1:whatever@gmail.com
name2:whatever@gmail.com
name3:whatever@gmail.com
```

etc

please i need the fully code cuz i dont have any info about perl just how i can use script
thanks a lot

i tried with this but not working its just print matching lines

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl 
# compare 
my $f1 = "list1.txt";
my $f2 = "list2.txt";
my $outfile = "result.txt";
my %results = (); 

open FILE1, "$f1" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while(my $line = <FILE1>){
   $results{$line}=1;
}
close(FILE1); 

open FILE2, "$f2" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while(my $line =<FILE2>) {  
   $results{$line}++;
}
close(FILE2);  

open (OUTFILE, ">$outfile") or die "Cannot open $outfile for writing \n";
foreach my $line (keys %results) {
   print OUTFILE " $results{$line} - $line" if $results{$line} != 1;
}
close OUTFILE;
```

Comment: "plz give me da codez" is not a question. Why not write this in some language you are familiar with rather than insisting on someone else writing the whole thing for you in Perl?

Comment: Simple `for` loop in bash will do the trick. No need to be a perl haxxxor.

Comment: Step 1: Create big regex that matches all names: `my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @names`. Step 2: echo only the lines in the second file that match `/^(?:$re):/`. I am sure the remaining I/O is trivial for you to implement.

Comment: im sorry mr Michael im not a programer and i serched for any program that do what i want i didnt find
please sir look at the code i write above can you make it work to save my time i spent alot of time serching
today thanks alot

Comment: I'm retracting my downvote on the question because it now at least *shows evidence of problem-solving effort* rather than being simply a request for someone else to do your work for you. It still isn't necessarily a *good* question, but it definitely isn't as bad as it was starting out.

Answer (score 3):

For each row in the second file, you want to lookup if the name in that row was found in the first file.

1. For each line in the second file,

   1. Extract the name from the line.
   2. If the name is present in the first file,

      1. Print the line.

That can be done efficiently by first creating a hash keyed by the names found in the first file.

1. Create a hash.
2. For each line in the first file,

   1. Extract the name from the line. (i.e. Remove the trailing newline.)
   2. Create an element in the hash keyed by the name.

Comment: thanks alot for reply sir but i dont know how i can creat hash
i cant find tut for it. i spent until now about 5 hourse serching and reading tut's that can make my code in perl and php
without any result 
i think if i serched for my 100 names with notebad easily more than try to write a program

Comment: @ikegami +1 for the steps. I made an attempt to write my first ever perl program. :)

Comment: @Shehab, `my %hash;`. And this isn't a code writing service. You're searching the wrong site if you're looking to hire a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this for reference. Please disregard if you can't use `awk`.

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} $1 in a' list1.txt list2.txt
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat list1.txt
name1
name2
name3
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat list2.txt
name2:whatever@gmail.com
name1:whatever@gmail.com
name3:whatever@gmail.com
name4:whatever@gmail.com
name5:whatever@gmail.com
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F: 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} $1 in a' list1.txt list2.txt
name2:whatever@gmail.com
name1:whatever@gmail.com
name3:whatever@gmail.com
```

#### Perl Solution: Disclaimer - I don't know much perl. I just followed @ikegami's suggestions and came up with following:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $LOOKUP, "<", "list1.txt" or die "Cannot open lookup file: $!";
open my $MASTER, "<", "list2.txt" or die "Cannot open Master file: $!";

my %names;
while (my $name = <$LOOKUP>) {
    chomp($name);
    ++$names{$name};
}

while (my $line = <$MASTER>) {
    my ($name) = split(/:/, $line);
    print $line if $names{$name};
}
```

Comment: Fixed: `"list1.txt" || die "..."` is the same thing as `"list1.txt"`. Assigning a simple value to the hash would be cheaper than assigning an array containing many empty strings. Inconsistent placement of `my $key` vs `my $line`. `exists` unnecessary if the value is always true (as it is in your code). `(my $x, my $y)` can be written as `my ($x, $y)`. No need to create variables that are never used (`$email`). Better to use lexicals rather than globals for file handles (or anything else). No need to explicitly close file handles if you're not going to check the result. Bad var names.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
grep -f list1.txt list2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

simply do it in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
namefile="./namefile"
bigfile="./bigemailfile"

while read name
do
    grep "^$name:" "$bigfile"
done < "$namefile"
```

or sort both files, like

```
sort -o list1.txt list1.txt
sort -o list2.tst list2.txt
```

and simply use:

```
join -t: list1.txt list2.txt
```

Hm.. nevermind - from your comment i understand than you using windows and not unix...

Comment: O(N*M)!! ow. This can be solved in O(N+M)

Comment: Mr jm666 i just download and installed linux os in vmware
i put ur bash sc with my two listes files listname1.txt and listbigemails2.txt
in same folder 
how can i edit your bash sc to run get my final ruslt
i tryed this

#!/bin/bash
namefile="./listname1.txt"
bigfile="listbigemails2.txt"

while read name
do
    grep "^$name:" "$bigfile"
done < "$namefile"

i got this error whats wrong

root@bt:/pentest# bash ./b.sh
: command not found
./b.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./b.sh: line 8: `done < "$namefile"'

Comment: @Shehab - please, edit your question where put readable error message. The posted script is working with bash, please copy it exactly.